# Not able to select from access db in vb with comparison of numeric values

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am not being able to retrieve from my access database in vb. Here is my code that points to the problem:

```
`cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  distinct(brought_date) from brought_coffee  where crop_year =? order by brought_date"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ccy", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cyrNote.SelectedItem.Trim)
        myData = cmd.ExecuteReader
        'MessageBox.Show(cyrNote.SelectedItem.Trim)

        While myData.Read()
            dte = myData(0)
            dtComb.Items.Add(dte)

        End While
        MessageBox.Show("dt1" & dte)`
```

The problem I have here seems to me that the comparison between is `crop_year =?` where `?` is the placeholder for `Convert.ToInt32(cyrNote.SelectedItem.Trim)` which is a value i get from a combobox `cyrNote` and try to convert it to an integer using `Convert.ToInt32()` so that it can be compared with the database value `crop_year` which is defined as integer in the database. The problem here though is that the select returns null. I tried to replace the placeholder `?` with a known value like "2011" and it returned a value. This means to me that my comparison `crop_year=Convert.ToInt32(cyrNote.SelectedItem.Trim)` is negative yet I expect something positive. I've tried to google on how to convert to integer and that is the best I could get. Can someone tell me how this conversion can be done well or in other words what could be the problem with my code?

Comment: What does your *MessageBox.Show* display when uncommented? If it shows 2011, then everything should work just fine.

Comment: The messagebox shows the default value of date variable `00:00:00` yet it is supposed to return something like `09/05/2012`. This probably means that there is no data being read

Comment: I meant this one: *MessageBox.Show(cyrNote.SelectedItem.Trim)*

Comment: Yeah of course that combobox `cyrNote` already has values like 2011, 2010 so the messagebox displays a value but the problem comes when I try to select values from database where the year in the database is same as the selected one in the combo

Comment: My last bet would be ... = Convert.ToInt32(cyrNote.Text.Trim). I have updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has nothing to do with named parameters. Rather, *SelectedItem* is of Object type. You should use either

```
cyrNote.SelectedText
```

or

```
cyrNote.Text
```

whichever works (depending on your combo box implementation)

Comment: Tried this but still no progress

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `?` with `@ccy` in the SQL statement.  You need to either use named parameters or ordinal parameters, but your SQL text expects ordinal, and your variable injection is named...

Comment: no, access use ? for parameters placeholders. There are not named parameters on access.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are not named parameters on access, try removing the name when you send it.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("", OleDb.OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cyrNote.SelectedItem.Trim)
```

should the the trick.

Also, if you can, change the code to use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Convert.ToInt32(cyrNote.SelectedItem.Trim));
```

You don´t need to specify anything when you are using access.